# Remove one level of a nested array

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can you change this array:

```
[["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]
```

to this?

```
["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]
```

### Clarification

My apologies for giving an invalid second version. This is what I'm really going for:

I want to add `["0","zero"]` to the beginning of `[["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]`, to get:

```
[["0","zero"], ["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]
```

I have tried:

```
["0","zero"] << [["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]
```

The above approach produces this, which contains a nesting I don't want:

```
[["0","zero"], [["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]]
```

Comment: Your second one isn't even valid...

Comment: Is it possible you meant `[{"1"=>"one"}, {"2"=>"two"}, {"3"=>"three"}]`

Comment: @mathepic, @ItayMoav - I just clarified my question. My apologies for not being clearer.

Comment: I think you should show some source code. I think it would help if we looked at how you are building the array in the first place. I suspect a misuse of `<<` when you probably should use `+=` instead.

Comment: I am trying to reach the same thing and I am stuck here... I am trying exactly now to make [[1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"],[4,"D"],[5,"E"]] into [1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"],[4,"D"],[5,"E], I remind that I already did one day it but I don't remember how could I do that, I was to open another topic here at SO but I saw you now and I am trying to take opportunity of the doubt, I have tried flatten but it returns me [1,"A",2,"B",3,"C",4,"D",5,"E] and not [1,"A"],[2,"B"],[3,"C"],[4,"D"],[5,"E]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unshift` ought to do it for you:

```
a = [["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]]
a.unshift(["0", "zero"])
=> [["0", "zero"], ["1", "one"], ["2", "two"], ["3", "three"]]
```

Comment: @WayneConrad - almost there. When I do this: `[["Inbox", 0]] << current_user.folders.collect{|folder| [folder.name, folder.id]}.flatten(1)`, I get: `[["Inbox", 0], ["My Folder", 132, "Fourth Folder", 133, "Third Folder", 134, "Fifth Folder", 135, "6th Folder", 136]]`

Comment: @Andrew Grimm, the `flatten(1)` is gone (the OP changed the question), so you can take away the +1 if you like :)

Comment: @WayneConrad - I still appreciate the `flatten(1)`. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: @WayneConrad - that's it! Thank you very much and sorry for that sloppy first question. +1

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for [flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280):

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of this array (recursively). That 
>   is, for every element that is an array, extract its elements into the new array. If the optional level argument determines the level of recursion to flatten.

```
[["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]].flatten
```

Which gives you:

```
=> ["1", "one", "2", "two", "3", "three"]
```

Comment: And to unnest the first array level?? I have tried flatten as how you showed but it returns me [1,"one",2,"two",3,"three"] and not [1,"one"],[2,"two"],[3,"three"]!

Answer (score 3):

`[["1","one"], ["2","two"], ["3","three"]].flatten`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your questions clearer, but is the following what you meant?

```
# Right answer
original = [["1","one"], ["2","two"]]
items_to_add = [["3","three"], ["4","four"]]
items_to_add.each do |item|
  original << item
end
original # => [["1", "one"], ["2", "two"], ["3", "three"], ["4", "four"]]

# Wrong answer
original = [["1","one"], ["2","two"]]
items_to_add = [["3","three"], ["4","four"]]
original << items_to_add # => [["1", "one"], ["2", "two"], [["3", "three"], ["4", "four"]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew. WayneConrad got the answer I was looking for using `unshift`. For posterity I've further clarified my original question.